# Get EventClicked from UserControl in aspx

Tags: c#, user-controls

Hei,
I would like get the name of the button who was clicked at usercontrol
I was tried this but I just get null:

UserControl uc = (UserControl)Page.FindControl("ImportTXP");

Answer (score 0):

If it's in your event handler, the sender will be the button that raised the event:

```
string name = ((Button)sender).Name;
```